# Neo4j querying a nodes that contain two specific ingredient names

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a question regarding a neo4j query, this is my query:

```
MATCH (o:Pizza)-[r:CONTAINS]->(p:Ingredient{name:"salami"}) RETURN o
```

my query works and it returns the pizza with the supplied ingredient but how would i add if it contains ham too i was trying something like this.

```
MATCH (o:Pizza)-[r:CONTAINS]->(p:Ingredient{name:"salami"}) and (p:Ingredient{name:"ham"}) RETURN o
```

Answer (score 2):

This query should work:

```
MATCH (o:Pizza)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Ingredient {name : 'salami'}),
(o)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Ingredient {name : 'ham'})
RETURN o
```

Using comma you can `MATCH` multiple incoming / outgoing relationships to the same node.

Alternatively, if you have a dynamic list of ingredients you can use the ALL function:

```
MATCH (o:Pizza)-[r:CONTAINS]->(p:Ingredient)
WITH o, collect(p.name) as ingredients 
WHERE ALL (ingredient IN ['salami', 'ham', 'another ingredient'] WHERE ingredient IN ingredients)
RETURN o
```